# Export large data issue

Tags: zend-framework, phpexcel

I am using zend 1 and phpexcel together.

When I export the data with limit 15000, its working fine and excel is generated but when I change the limit of data to 18000 it show me The connection was reset page.

**Note** : when I use the columns 13 or less then 13 its working fine but when I increase the columns for excel it show me The connection was reset page

How can I resolve this issue, please help me.

Comment: Start by looking at your logs, see if they report anything.... but without more information, all anybody can do is make wild guesses.... most likely potential causes are timeout and/or memory limits

Comment: When i on the display error, its show me one warning and lots of notice

Answer (score 0):

It's not explicit in your description, but I assume you are getting a web request, generating a large Excel file on the fly, and then sending that (complete with correct headers) to the waiting client.

There are two comments that come to mind.

**Offload heavy processing**

Generally speaking, it is not advisable to do this kind of large scale processing on the fly for a waiting client. Better to offload the large file generation to another server and then provide a link to the waiting client.

There are two reasons for this:

1. The client is waiting. If the processing time is long enough, the client request might timeout. The server has then done most/all of the work for nothing and the client doesn't even get his response.
2. If you make the web-server do that large-scale processing, then the other web visitors - even ones with small, simple requests - will possibly have their performance negatively impacted by the single process eating up resources.

**Reduce PHPExcel memory usage with caching**

Of course, off-loading the heavy-lifting to another server doesn't make the memory problem go away; it just transfers the issue to the new server.

Probably the first thing to try for PHPExcel is to use their [cell-caching functionality](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/04-Configuration-Settings.md).

This allows different backends - filesystem, memcache, sqllite, etc - to *simulate* having more memory. The tradeoff here, of course, is speed. It's much slower to use external simulated memory than to use in-server actual memory. But the upside is that such memory is "effectively" unlimited, so you can at least get the job done.

As noted above, for a web request, the job may still take longer than the client is willing to wait, so you may be forced to offload that heavy lifting to another server. But at least the caching approach gives you a shot at servicing the request without memory overflow.